# Dos Batch String Manipulation using variable

Tags: batch-file, powershell

I want to do the following throuhg a Dos Batch or Powershell.

- a) get ip of local machine and assign to a variable
- b) store the variable for later use.
- c) read an xml file
- d) replace a specific entry in xml file (an ip address) with the ip stored in variable
- e) the value i want to replace is declared inside a tag like so, <"MyOwnIp=127.0.0.1">
- f) save changes to a new file
- g) rename old file, rename new file, delete old file

I tried the following but due to lack of scripting knowledge and experience, I am at a loss.

```
@echoff
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set /p myIp= my ip address is %myIp%
echo %myIp% 
FOR /F "skip=3 tokens=1-4 delims=</>" %%I in (file.xml) DO
 set "oldIp=%%I"
 (if !oldIp! neq !myIp! do 
  set !oldIp:myip=%newIp%!
  echo !oldIp!)
endlocal  
pause
```

Can anyone help? Thank you.

Comment: Shouldn't `echoff` be `echo off`? And what is the exact problem that you are running into?

Comment: hi. thank you both for the feedback.

Comment: JensG: You are correct. It was a typo on my behalf. I ran script test using @echo off.                                         Alexander Obersht: the complete tag is <MyOwnIp="127.0.0.1" />. Admittedly the example I gave was poor, my apology. I shall explore the select-xml cmdlet option. Personally i prefer to do it in dos but if this extend beyond what dos can do, powershell will have to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, here's an example of well-formed XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- test comment -->
<foo>
    <!-- 
        Note that 'bar' here is an element, 'MyOwnIp' is an attribute of the
        element and only the attribute value is inside the double quotes.
    -->
    <bar MyOwnIp="127.0.0.1" />
</foo>
```

So unfortunately what you have isn't valid XML. In my opinion this circumstance alone makes using XML redundant because if it's not valid you can't properly edit it (with PowerShell cmdlets for example). About the only reason to ever use XML is that it ensures *you won't have to do string manipulation* on anything (except maybe #text).

Now on to editing. Since you wanted a batch file:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

:: Prompting user to enter IP address.
set /p myIp=enter IP address:
echo %myIp%

:: Reading input file line by line.
for /F "usebackq tokens=*" %%l in (`type "file.xml"`) do (
    set line=%%l

    :: Splitting the current line on '<' and '=' characters and saving the first
    :: substring in the %attr% variable.
    for /F "usebackq tokens=1 delims=<=" %%a in ('!line!') do (
        set attr=%%~a
        if /I "!attr!" EQU "myownip" (
            :: This is the line we want to change. Writing (appending) edited line
            :: to a new file. '^' escapes special characters.
            echo ^<"MyOwnIp=%myIp%" /^> >> newfile.xml
        ) else (
            :: Writing unchanged line.
            echo !line! >> newfile.xml
        )
    )
)

endlocal  
pause
```

Renaming and deleting files is trivial so I trust you'll figure it out yourself.

Answer (score 1):

This is the final script and it works. For the help, I can only offer thanks and positive feedback      :)

I have had to modify a few areas in essence it works. It is wonderful what batch scripting can do.

```
    ::Script for changing IP String in an XML file
    ::Author Alexander Obersht, AQuader 
    ::09/07/2014, 10:29am (bst)
    ::Information Source: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24573503/dos-batch-string-  manipulation-using-variable/24577552#24577552

cd /d "%ProgramFiles%\My Working Directory"
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

for /F "tokens=2 delims:" in %%b ('ipconfig ^|find "IPv4 Address"') do (
set myIp=%%b)
echo %myIp%

for /F "usebackq tokens=*" %%1 in (file.xml) do (
set line=%%1
 for /F "usebackq tokens=1 delims=<=" in ('!line!') do (
 set attr=%%~a
  if /I "!attr!" equ "IP Own" (
  echo ^<IP Own=%myIp% /^> >> file.txt 
  else !line! >> file.txt
  )
 )
)
endlocal
ren file.xml file.old
ren file.txt file.xml
pause
```

Answer (score 0):

This Powershell script will do what you are asking. It assumes the following xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Settings>
    <MyOwnIp>127.0.0.1</MyOwnIp>
</Settings>
```

This is the Powershell:

```
$ipAddr = ((ipconfig | findstr [0-9].\.)[0]).Split()[-1]

$file = 'C:\Directory\MySettings.xml'
[xml]$xdoc = Get-Content $file
$node = $xdoc.SelectSingleNode("/Settings/MyOwnIp]")
$node.InnerText = $ipAddr

Copy-Item -Path $file -Destination "$file`.bak"
$xdoc.Save($file)
```

Comment: Hi WiiBopp, Thank you for the ps script. I shall give it a try and get back to you with feedback.